# Spring Security Basic Authorization for REST Client

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have two applications. One of them called **frontend** has spring security activated and is working properly with a login prompt. When it comes to the other application called **module** which wants to use Spring's `RestTemplate` to do a post request to an REST Endpoint of my application it just does not work.

Testing the authorization attempt with `curl` yields the following result:

```
C:\Users\me>curl -i -X Post -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" http://localhost:8080/log/get
HTTP/1.1 403
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=AC71E702C00D5FA73F0EF0F81C5439D6; Path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 21 Dec 2017 11:43:53 GMT

{"timestamp":1513856633878,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.","path":"/log/get"}
```

Please see my configuration to actually apply basic auth

**web-security-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">

    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <!--<intercept-url pattern="/log/*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>-->
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

        <form-login
                login-page=''
                default-target-url="/manager"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"/>

        <logout logout-success-url="/login"/>

    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="comaUserDetailsService"/>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

**CustomBasicAuthEntryPoint.java**

```
@Component
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {
  //  Code Quelle:
  //  http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-basic-authentication/
  @Override
  public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request,
                       final HttpServletResponse response,
                       final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    //Authentication failed, send error response.
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" + getRealmName() + "");

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println("HTTP Status 401 : " + authException.getMessage());
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    setRealmName("Coma-Frontend");
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
  }
}
```

Comment: seems to me you have csrf enabled., since you want to hit you api from another spring boot app this one not being an html form. Why not disable it?

Comment: What part of the error message: *Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.* do you not understand? It is clear that you have no session with a CSRF token saved.You didn't send the session id with your request.

Comment: @dur any guide on how to provide the csrf session with spring ?

Comment: You just have to add the `JSESSIONID` cookie to your request. To get a session id, you have to make a HTTP `GET` request first. But that's not a good solution, because REST is defined as stateless. So better write your own conifguration for REST, without CSRF and without any session. You can find some examples on SO.